# Particiones Disco Gentoo y Partición tipo GPT

Tags: linux, gentoo

Buenas soy un usuario medio de sistemas Linux, y me apetece meterme en el follón que supone Gentoo, tengo un "problemilla" a la hora de la instalación:

Estoy instalándolo desde mi distribución que es Ubuntu, y aquí ya empiezan mis problemas, quiero hacer la partición del disco(que bueno después de informamre por google, usaré un sistema de "carpetas" por defecto , que es el que viene en todos los tutoriales de internet.

Os adjunto la imagen de como están distribuidas mis particiones que me creó Ubuntu al instalarlo:

[image: PARTICIONES]

Bien, ¿Que ocurre? , pues para empezar que tengo que hacer las particiones desde la partición 2 (/dev/sda2). Pero al estar logeado desde mi usuario (Por lo que he leido) No puedo acceder a desmontar el disco (para redimensionarlo y hacer mis particiones) ya que estoy "usando" mi carpeta personal que está en esa partición.

¿Alguna idea de como logearme como root, sin tener que logearme con mi usuario? ¿ O alguna forma para desmontar la partición y redimensionarla ?

Y respecto a las particiones GPT, cual es la diferencia entre las particiones MBR y GPT, no llego a entender muy bien que ventajas y desventajas tiene cada una.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Con una live image puedes redimensionar tu partición. ¿Qué particiones GPT? Si no las conoces no las uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazte un Pen Drive con la iso del gparted.
Arranca la maquina desde el Pen Drive y podrás modificar la partición sin grandes problemas.
Otra opción mas sencilla y con muchas más ventajas, es que te crees una maquina virtual con VMware o VirtualBox, e instales Gentoo en ella.

Un saludo.